# How to fill web page with image without stretching the image?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when I tried to fill my web page with an image. When I fill my web page with an image that I selected, the image will become bigger and will scroll down to see the rest of the image. I want the image to not scroll down and not stretches the image, which maintains the original looks of the image. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Global Shopping Mall</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
  .mySlides {display: none}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:2000px;">
  <!-- Automatic Slideshow Images -->

  <div id="mySlides" class="mySlides w3-display-container  w3-display-topright w3-center">
  <img src="http://gshopping-mall.com/images/consv3.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;object-position:center;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;">
  <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Page Content -->
</div>
</footer> -->
<script>
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 4 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

having `style="width:100%;height:100%;` makes the container take up the size of the contents. You need to do `style="width:auto;height:100vh;` to set the height as the height of the display and the width will be automatically adjusted, or you can flip them to have `style="width:100vw;height:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is that the image can be visible without the need of do scroll in the page you can set the object-fit property to "Contain" instead of "Cover", so your img tag will be:

```
<img src="http://gshopping-mall.com/images/consv3.png" style="width:100%;height: 100%;object-fit: contain;object-position:center;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;max-height: 100vh;">
```

The problem with this is that the image will not fill the width of the page.

If you want that the image fills the width and don't be stretch you will have to create a new image modifying the proportions of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`. `vw` stands for Viewport Width, `vh` stands for Viewport Height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613677446614-1039482c157f">
```